# Spring batch to process mainframe Binary file

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I am using simplebinarybufferedreader inside a flat file reader to read the mainframe binary file but for some reason I am having issues where the code will not read all the lines from the file and it only reads the first record and finishes the job. It is encoded as cp1047. I have seen your previous demos where you are using jrecord and cb2xml libraries to process mainframe binary files but we are trying to avoid using these libraries. Do you have a code snippet you can share how to process mainframe binary file without using cb2xml and jrecord.
Thanks

Comment: `I have seen your previous demos where you are .. `: who are you talking/writing to? Please share a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces your issue to be able to help you.

Comment: Do you have a sample code where i can read mainframe binary file that is using cp1047 encoding and process it using simplebinarybufferedreader.

Comment: You can find examples of how to use the SimpleBinaryBufferedReader here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/main/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/test/java/org/springframework/batch/item/file/SimpleBinaryBufferedReaderFactoryTests.java#L29

Comment: public ItemReader<Sales> reader() throws FileNotFoundException {
        InputStream inputStream = util.getFileInputStream(SOURCE_BUCKET_NAME, "Sales");
        return new CustomReader(inputStream);
    }

Comment: public void initialize(InputStream inputStream) { SimpleBinaryBufferedReaderFactory factory = new SimpleBinaryBufferedReaderFactory(); factory.setLineEnding("         "); try { BufferedReader br = factory.create(new InputStreamResource(inputStream), "cp1047"); String line; line = br.readLine(); while (line != null ) { Sales sales = new Sales(); sales.setPartNbr(line.substring(0,8)); sales.setSrcCdNbr(line.substring(8,13)); sales.setPltNbr(line.substring(13,16)); salesData.add(sales); line=br.readLine(); } } catch (IOException e) { } }

Comment: @Override
    public Sales read() {
        Sales sales = null;
        if (nextSalesIndex < salesData.size()) {
            sales = salesData.get(nextSalesIndex);
            nextSalesIndex++;
        }
        else {
            nextSalesIndex = 0;
        }
        return sales;
    }

Comment: public CustomReader(InputStream inputStream) {
        initialize(inputStream);
    }

Comment: Cuurently this is how i am reading the file from Amazon S3 Bucket and then created a custom reader that accepts an input stream and then intializes the file to an object and then reads the initzlize data in read function. What will be the better approach

Comment: Please do not put code in comments, as you can see it is not readable. You can always edit your question and add your formatted code along with your specific issue/question.